# Dynamic data from background refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

Is there a way to have a background refresh of some php scripts i have already provided..
I just want these scripts to refresh every 5 seconds so that i would be able to record/view dynamic data..

iam using this on the header of my site:

```
   sample url http://www.example.com/scripts

   setTimeout('window.location="/scripts";',5000);
```

But the after refresh it goes to the url..I just want it to be refreshed(updated) without redirecting to it.. Is it possible?Some sample?..

Best Regards..

Comment: its not an *or*, its ajax with or with or without jquery

Comment: can you provide me a sample..thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with **jQuery**:

```
$('body').load( url,[data],[callback] );
```

Read more at [docs.jquery.com / Ajax / load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback)

Answer (score 2):

The best method of using this is using AJAX and having a php file which would change those variables. This way you do not have to refresh the page but just ask the server for an update. On the `completed` callback change what you have to change on the client based on the response of the server. You have plenty of AJAX tutorials on the web.